# How can I download a file outside web directory using PHP without appending HTML content to file?

Tags: php

I am having trouble writing a single PHP script that displays an HTML text-box that will search for a file in the /tmp directory of a Linux machine.  Once the user types the string into the text box and presses the submit button, matching hyperlinks will be presented underneath the textbox with names of the files outside the web directory (in /tmp).

When I click the hyperlink, I want to download the file from the /tmp directory.  Unfortunately, because I need to use a single php script, HTML content is being appended to the file since I am using the php header command.

Is there any way I can download the file without having html from my php page appended to the file and without using more than a single php script?

```
<?php


function displayfiles()
{
    echo '<ul>';

    if ($handle = opendir('/tmp')) 
    {
        while ($file = readdir($handle))
        {
            if ($file != "." && $file != ".." && (strstr($file, $_POST['searchbox'])))
            {
                echo '<li><a href="search.php?file='.$file.'">'.$file.'</a></li>';
            }
            else if ($file != "." && $file != ".." && (eregi($file, $_POST['searchbox'])))
            {
                echo '<li><a href="search.php?file='.$file.'">'.$file.'</a></li>';  
            }
        }
        closedir($handle);
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}

function downloadfile($filename)
{            
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; file='/tmp/$filename' filename=$filename");
        header("Content-Length: " . filesize("/tmp/$filename"));
        header("Pragma: no-cache");
        header("Expires: 0");
        readfile("/tmp/$filename");
    exit(); 
}


echo 
"<html>
<head>
<title>File Search</title>
</head>
<body>
        <form method='POST'>
        <input id='searchbox' name='searchbox' id='searchbox' type='textbox' />
        <input type='submit' name='submit' />
        </form>";

                if (isset($_POST['submit']))
                {
                    displayfiles();        
                }
                else if (isset($_GET['file']) && file_exists("/tmp/".$_GET['file']))
                {
            downloadfile($_GET['file']);
        }

 echo "</body></html>";
?>
```

Comment: `return` exits the current scope, in this case the script. The last echo won't be executed any longer. http://php.net/return - Also your system can be tampered and attacked because this is open to injection and traversal attacks.

Comment: You could add an `exit;` after the `readfile` line.

Comment: If I add an exit the downloaded file still has HTML content before the file content.  Am I going about this the correct way?

Comment: @user1691103: Yes, just do not output anything before and afterwards, that simple it is. Do you know what a `function` is and how you can write your own?

Comment: Thank you, and yes I can encapsulate my logic into a function.  The restriction is that the  browser must stay on the same page and a download dialog has to pop up?  In other words I can use only one script for the function.

Comment: Sure, that's why you put your two types of page functionality into a function each. Then you can decide on top before doing any output which of the two scripts you call a) Form and Listing b) Header based download.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to handle the output of the file-download before outputting anything else, quick and dirty example (even only with one function instead of two as suggested in the comment, I think you get the idea):

```
<?php

function action_download() {
    if (!isset($_GET['file'])) return FALSE;
    $file = sprintf('/tmp/%s', $_GET['file']);
    $file = realpath($file);
    if (substr($file, 0, 5) !== '/tmp/') return FALSE;
    if (!is_file($file) || !is_readable($file)) return FALSE;

    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename='".basename($file)."'");
    header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file));
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");
    readfile($file);
    return TRUE;
}

if (action_download()) return;

?>
<head>
<title>File Search</title>
</head>
<body>
        <form method='POST'>
        <input id='searchbox' name='searchbox' id='searchbox' type='textbox' />
        <input type='submit' name='submit' />
        </form>
<?php
                if (isset($_POST['submit']))
                {
                        echo '<ul>';

                         if ($handle = opendir('/tmp')) {
                                while ($file = readdir($handle))
                                {
                                  if ($file != "." && $file != ".." && (strstr($file, $_POST['searchbox'])))
                                  {
                                        echo '<li><a href="search.php?file='.$file.'">'.$file.'</a></li>';
                                  }
                  else if ($file != "." && $file != ".." && (eregi($file, $_POST['searchbox'])))
                  {
                        echo '<li><a href="search.php?file='.$file.'">'.$file.'</a></li>';  
                  }
                                }
                          closedir($handle);
                          }
                        echo '</ul>';
                }
?>
</body></html>
```

Also take care that there can be data inside `/tmp/` that should not be offered for download as it can be used to attack applications, their users or even the system.

Comment: Is there a way to prevent any html that precedes the function call to not be outputted to the file.  This is where I am stuck.  Because I am using headers this problem occurs.  Can this be done without headers?

Comment: @user1691103: See the script above, that's the whole script. There is no output before the function call.

Comment: When I create a file abcd containing the number 1234 in it inside /tmp and then search for abcd and download the file contains html tags from the script before the value 1234.

Comment: @user1691103: Please make yourself comfortable with some of PHP's basic workings: http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php